# serialize an array of strings and null values

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf to serialize json from api for flutter app.
however I'm having an issue where I need to serialize this list for example:

```
"value_array": [ "",
                    "",
                    null
                ]
```

If I use the usual:

```
repeated string value_array = 6;
```

I get an exception during parsing the json.

and sadly I can't have the json changed from api. even worse I can't just manually remove the null from json before parsing it as this element in json is repeated in many different api calls.

PS. I don't need to differentiate the empty string from null, just want to avoid the exception.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried usign the [StringValue](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.StringValue) field? Like `repeated google.protobuf.StringValue value_array = 6`;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Despite the fact that I need to modify the app to change from :
```ValueArray().add("abc");```
to something like this:
```ValueArray().add(StringValue()..value = "abc");```

However the main issue still the same, the app can't parse the json above as a ```repeated google.protobuf.StringValue value_array = 6```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

protobuf has a *very* opinionated view on JSON, and not all JSON concepts map cleanly to protobuf concepts; for example, protobuf *has no notion of null*

It might be fine and reasonable to use the protobuf JSON variant if you're always talking protobuf-to-protobuf and want readability (hence text over binary), but if you're working with an external (non-protobuf) JSON tool, honestly: don't use protobuf. Use *any relevant JSON-specific tool for your platform* - it will do a better job of handling the JSON and supporting your needs. You can always re-map that data to your protobuf model after you have deserialized it, if you need.

Comment: Thanks, I don't really need to differentiate null from empty string, I only hope for a way that I can avoid running through the exception.
whiIe protobuf can handle null for string on its own by deflating it to an empty string, but not if it's in a repeated string.

Hope there is a workaround this.